# Webpack: split vendor and app code

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I setup React+Webpack project. It take 60s to build an initial bundle, and 1s to append incremental change but I even don't have my application code yet! Seems that bundle of node_modules is very expensive. I tried splitting using common chunks, but it didn't give performance improvement.

How can I make Webpack bundle node_modules only once, and even don't watch for changes in this dir?

Comment: Have you looked into [DLL](https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#dynamic-linked-library)s? That approach would allow you to generate a DLL once and update it whenever your vendor dependencies happen to change. This can avoid a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah, I saw about DLLs but I didn't manage to make them work. Can you please provide an example how I can achieve a complete bundle of node_modules that are build only once?

Comment: I'll try to craft something. Currently the online examples [1](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/dll) and [2](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/dll-user) are your best bet. Is there something particular missing there?

Answer (score 2):

If that's a problem, you don't need to bundle external dependencies in your project. You can add them as external dependencies. For that, of course, you should add the scripts to your page.

Let's say you add the react and react-dom scripts to your page, in the webpack config file you could add this:

```
{
  externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  } 
}
```

What this tells webpack is every time you require('react') or webpack will return a global variable called React. Same thing if you require('react-dom')

And for every loader, you should either include the files you want or exclude the files you don't need.

Here's an example excluding node_modules:

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or even more performant, you can just include the files you need:

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: './src',
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to bundle all external dependencies into 1 file so then webpack could replace require('react') with React from that file?

Comment: You could with some configuration, but if you're doing that you're still going to have the same issues you're having today, which is webpack having to bundle all of your dependencies.